# Junit cannot detect an @Autowired Bean during a test of a configuration class in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I have a configuration class like the following

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Bean
  SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall() {
    return new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("");
  }

}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this configuration class. My test class looks like the following.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Configuration.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ConfigurationTest {

  ApplicationContextRunner context = new ApplicationContextRunner()
                                         .withUserConfiguration(Configuration.class);

  @Test
  public void should_check_presence_of_example_service() {
    context.run(it -> {
      assertThat(it).hasSingleBean(SimpleJdbcCall.class);
    });
  }
}
```

When I am running the test in the `ConfigurationTest` class, I am getting an error like the one below.

> Error creating bean with name 'Configuration': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I tried to solve this by crating a bean jdbcTemplate in the Configuration class and passed datasource. Then the test unit test does not find the bean datasource. After that I used @TestConfiguration in the ConfigurationTest class and crated a mock(jdbcTemplate). That did not work either.

Comment: Nahid bhai, you are getting this error because your tests cannot find `JdbcTemplate` bean. So in your `@ContextConfiguration`, add another class which contains `JdbcTemplate` bean definition. However, since these are unit tests (if these are functional tests then below suggestion does not apply), it is not wise to use real `JdbcTemplate` as it could be making calls to real database, hence, create a test configuration, create a bean that returns `JdbcTemplate`, and return a Mock instance of `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Is this spring or spring boot?

Comment: Depending on that you either need to define the `@Bean` for the `jdbcTemplate` and its dependecies like `DataSource`. With Spring Boot a shortcut like `@DataJpaTest` might be available.

Comment: This is spring boot. I changed the tag. I tried the provided solutions already before I asked this question here. In my case, those solutions did not work. I edited my questions to describe that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, and I thought it might be helpful for others if someone is in the same situation. Actually my goal was to increase the test coverage because of the company requirement, and the following solution works for me.

I changed my configuration class like below

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

  @Bean
  SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("");
  }

}
```

I had to change my test class like below. Now the test class is not complaining, and I am getting 100% coverage of the Configuration class.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ConfigurationTest {

  @TestConfiguration
  static class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
      return mock(DataSource.class);
    }
  }

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private Configuration configuration;

  @Test
  public void should_check_presence_of_simpleJdbcCall_Bean() {
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = configuration.simpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(simpleJdbcCall);
  }

}
```